# .NetCore CancellationToken with MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, api, .net-core, cancellationtokensource

1. Would you please confirm if this implementation of **CancellationToken** works as recommended?
2. At what line the operations will get canceled?

Any explanation is very helpful and appreciated!

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository {
    const string _collectionName = "Users";
    private readonly IMongoCollection<AppUser>? _collection;
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken; 

    // constructor - dependency injection
    public UserRepository(IMongoClient client, IMongoDbSettings dbSettings) {
        var database = client.GetDatabase(dbSettings.DatabaseName);
        _collection = database.GetCollection<AppUser>(_collectionName);
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    }
    
    // GetUser from db
    public async Task<UserDto?> GetUser(string userId) {
        var user = await _collection.Find<AppUser>(user => 
            user.Id == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync(_cancellationToken);

        return new UserDto {
            //some code
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The operation will never be cancelled as it is now. What is your usecase for the cancellation token here? When would you expect it to be cancelled?

Comment: you don't cancel your token, so it will never be cancelled. See microsoft documentation

Comment: Would you please correct my code so it does cancel the operations while the user closes the browser, etc. ?

Comment: you should call `Cancel` for CancellationTokenSource on the level that is aware of browser state (which is def higher level than db level). See how CancellationTokensSource works here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-6.0